# Wird „gemeinsam“ hier als Substantiv oder als eine andere Wortart gebraucht?

Tags: nominalization

Meine Frage ist, ob man in diesem Satz *gemeinsam* großschreibt und wenn, warum?

> Wir gehen oft *gemeinsam / Gemeinsam* dorthin.

Comment: Warum sollte *gemeinsam* hier großgeschrieben werden?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Die Antwort ist: nein!

Hier ist *gemeinsam* ein Adverb wie jedes andere:

> Wir gehen oft [*gemeinsam*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/gemeinsam) ([*zusammen*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/zusammen)/ [*alleine*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/alleine)/ [*schnell*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/schnell)/ [*müde*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/m%C3%BCde)/ [*rückwärts*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/r%C3%BCckw%C3%A4rts) …) dorthin.

Alle diese Adverbien werden kleingeschrieben. Es sind eben keine Substantive. Da ich nicht erkennen kann, worin Ihre Zweifel gründen, lässt sich dazu auch nicht viel mehr sagen.

Comment: Es ist mir völlig unverständlich, wie OP hier auf Großschreibung kommt. Deshalb verstehe ich auch die Antwort anstelle eines close-votes nicht.

Comment: @Olafant, zweifelsohne wäre die Frage wesentlich besser, hätte der OP uns seine Gedanken mitgeteilt. Unabhängig davon hat seine Ja–Nein-Frage eine eindeutige und begründbare Antwort.